# Sort pandas dataframe within groups

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
>>> df
     Category  Score
0        A      1
1        A      2
2        A      3
3        B      5
4        B      9
```

I expect the output:
Sorting Score within Category.

```
>>> df
     Category  Score
2        A      3
1        A      2
0        A      1
4        B      9
3        B      5
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use `sort_values` by mention order.

```
In [17]: df.sort_values(by=['Category', 'Score'], ascending=[True, False])
Out[17]:
  Category  Score
2        A      3
1        A      2
0        A      1
4        B      9
3        B      5
```